# Java Enums and Fields with same name

Tags: java, enums

I was refactoring some code recently and ended up with a weird compiler error

```
class CustomerContract{
    public enum BillingTerm{
        MONTHLY,QUARTERLY,YEARLY;
    }

    public String BillingTerm = "";
}

class SalesProposal{
    public String billingCycles(){
        String message = "We have several billing cycles available: \n";
        for(CustomerContract.BillingTerm term : CustomerContract.BillingTerm.values()){
            message += " - " + term.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error on SalesProposal because it attempts to access the `String` rather than the enum.

What I'm surprised by is that `CustomerContract` did not cause a compiler. Can someone explain to me why, and how I might have explicitly referenced the `enum`?

Please forgive the convention issues my contrived example.

Comment: "... it attempts to access the `String`" - What is "it"? Also, please add the full compiler error. The easiest fix would be to start your variable names with lower case letters...

Comment: Probabily "values" of CustomerContract.BillingTerms are String.

Comment: Are the variables declared as in your real-world problem? I'm surprised that you could access an object variable with a class reference.

Comment: I think when you do `CustomerContract.BillingTerm` its ambiguous because are you referring to the String, or the enum, hence the compiler error. Surely the compiler error says something like ambiguous reference

Comment: If you delete SalesProposal class, does CustomerContract compile on its own?  Maybe the compile WOULD have complained about CustomerContract, but the SalesProposal errors got there first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in many cases (e.g. 2 interfaces with same-name constants both implemented by a class), introducing naming ambiguity does not immediately affect compilation, as long as those ambiguous names are not referenced, thus causing the compiler to be unable to disambiguate.

In your case, the issue is the part of the for-each loop that defines the iterable.

Instead of interpreting `CustomerContract.BillingTerm` as the `enum BilligTerm`, it interprets it as the homonymous `String` instance field, and will likely complain about a `static` reference to a non-`static` member, ignoring the fact that you are trying to reference the `enum` altogether.

The best practice would be to:

- Not shadow a field name with a nested class/enum's name
- Follow the variable naming [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and use `camelBack` for variables (which de facto would achieve point 1 in this case)